# Codeigniter 2.1 - Call function in __construct

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am having following functions:

```
public function admin_login_check()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == FALSE)
        redirect('admin/admin_login');
}
```

and this one (for the moment):

```
public function index()
{
    $this->admin_login_check();
    $data['title'] = 'Početna | TOP';
    $data['main_content'] = 'admin_home';
    $data= $this->data + $data;
    $this->load->view('admin/admin_template', $data);

}

public function admin_login()
{
        $data['title'] = 'Prijava | TOP';
        $data['main_content'] = 'admin_login';
        $data= $this->data + $data;
        $this->load->view('admin/admin_template', $data);
}
```

When I `$this->admin_login_check()` inside `__construct` function I get following error:

> The web page at xxx/admin/admin_login has resulted in too many redirects.

Comment: You forgot to paste the error

Comment: I am sorry. Added error.

Comment: Can you post the code of the page in `admin/admin_login`?

Comment: Well you basically have a redirect loop.

Comment: @Jeffrey Added code for the admin_login.

Comment: @azizpunjani, where do you see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are having too many redirects is because when you place

```
$this->admin_login_check();
```

inside your `admin`'s constructor controller. This will always run on each method/function inside your `admin` controller.

And since you redirected to the same `admin` controller,

```
redirect('admin/admin_login');
```

It will check first if you're logged out, so it will try to redirect you again and again.
One solution is to actually separate your `admin_login` page on a separate controller. Maybe the `home` controller if you have that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make one check for current method name as:

```
public function admin_login_check()
{
    $loged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') ? TRUE : FALSE;
    if($this->router->method != 'admin_login' && $loged_in==FALSE)
        redirect('admin/admin_login');
}
```

The IF checks if you are at any page except the admin_login page and you are not logged in.

How ever I think this method for redirecting is little wrong. 
It will be a lot better if you make one function is_admin to return TRUE/FALSE and do something like this...

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if($this->is_admin() == FALSE && $this->router->method != 'admin_login')
        redirect('admin/admin_login');
}

public function is_admin()
{
    return $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```